# Every tree a path exists which connects two leaves and removing that path the remaining graph is still a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I wanted to prove that that in any tree $G$ with $2k$ leaves, there are $k$ edge-disjoint paths with endpoints being leaves of $G$.

To solve this I tried to use induction. In the induction step there are $2k + 2$ leaves. Now I want to find a path $P$ which connects two leaves and removing it leaves behind a tree with $2k$ or $2k +1$ leaves.

Such a path has to contain at most one vertex with degree $\ge 3$. Otherwise the remaining graph could be a forest.

So I have tried to solve it algorithmically. Let $P$ be a path which connects two leaves $a$ and $b$. If $P$ contains multiple vertices with degree $\ge 3$, remove the edge which connects the one vertex $s$ with degree $\ge  3$ with next one. So we have now a path from $a$ to $s$. The $s$' degree is at least $2$. So there is path to another leaf $c$. If there is again a vertex $t$ we remove the edge leading to $s$. And now we have a path from $c$ to $t$. If we repeat it multiple times we will get a path with at most one vertex with degree $\ge 3$.

Removing the path means that we remove everything except the vertex with degree $\ge 3$.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried.  What techniques are available to you?  Where are you stuck?  Please **edit the question** to provide this information.  Questions that don't demonstrate an independent effort to reach a solution usually attract downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My bad.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open.  There seems to be a good bit of context in the present post.

Answer (score 0):

What does your theorem state about this tree?

[image: tree graph]

Comment: the remaining graph has no vertices and therefore no cycles. So it is a tree, isnt it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1690627)

Comment: @Kman:  Of *course* I couldn't post an image in a comment... that's why I posted this as an "answer" (as a proposed counter-example).  Clear?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Fair, but your answer is in the form of a question back to the questioner, which to me does not constitute an answer. However, that's just me; others may feel differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is false (even for undirected trees, which is presumably the intended setting). To see this, take a star with at least five vertices. Any path between leaves has three vertices, and after removing the path the remaining graph isn't even connected.

Comment: A star can't be a tree because there is a cycle.

Comment: @Creaser A [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) is a tree with one internal vertex and the rest leaves.  But the point here is that when you remove the path, you don't remove the internal vertex.

Comment: @RobertIsrael if you don't remove internal vertices of the path, then a subdivided star works instead. However, you can always find a path such that removing its edges and all but one vertex gives a tree.

Comment: You remove the vertices that have no edges remaining.

Comment: Removing the path means that we remove everything except the vertix with degree >= 3